# Swift Array of Functions

Tags: swift

I'm very new to Swift, but slowly learning by following the [Stanford iTunes U course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099). I have a question about storing and calling functions in an array.

The code I have (below) seems to store the function properly, but when I try to call one of the functions I get this error: `'(IntegerLiteralConvertible, IntegerLiteralConvertible) -> $T6' is not identical to (String, Op)`.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418951/array-of-functions-in-swift#24447484) that was helpful in getting to where I am, but now I'm stuck.

```
enum Op {
    case binary((Double, Double) -> Double)
}

var ops = [String: Op]()

func addOperation(symbol: String, op: Op) {
    ops[symbol] = op
}

addOperation("×", Op.binary(*))
addOperation("÷", Op.binary({ $1 / $0 }))
addOperation("+", Op.binary(+))
addOperation("−", Op.binary({ $1 - $0 }))

var newValue = ops["÷"](6, 3) // Produces the error
```

My understanding was that `ops["÷"]` should be the function I stored in the array earlier. Am I not calling it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Nate Cook answer is corret but why do you have to use enum in this case? Consider using typealias like following :

```
var ops = [String: Op]()

    func addOperation(symbol: String, op:Op) {
        ops[symbol] = op
    }

    addOperation("×", (*))
    addOperation("÷", ({ $1 / $0 }))
    addOperation("+", (+))
    addOperation("−", ({ $1 - $0 }))

    var newValue = ops["÷"]?(3,6)

// you have to put this outside of any class
public typealias Op = (Double, Double) -> Double
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your post come in! Good idea ;)

Comment: Is there any advantage to using an enum?

Comment: @Phil An enumeration defines a common type for a group of related values and enables you to work with those values in a type-safe way within your code. In your case enum hold a single value only thats why you should consider using typealias

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems there. First, subscripting a dictionary returns an optional value, so `ops["÷"]` is an `Op?` that needs to be unwrapped before you can use it.

Second, the associated value of an `enum` can't be accessed directly—you can only get the value when pattern matching in a `switch` statement. I'd suggest adding a computed property to `Op` that does the work for you:

```
enum Op {
    case binary((Double, Double) -> Double)

    var binaryCall: ((Double, Double) -> Double)? {
        switch self {
        case let .binary(operation):
            return operation
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like this instead:

```
var newValue = ops["÷"]?.binaryCall?(6, 3)
// Optional(0.5)
```

An alternate method of implementation would be to just build an dictionary of binary operations, like so (you still need to unwrap once, though):

```
typealias BinaryOp = (Double, Double) -> Double

var binaryOps: [String: BinaryOp] = [:]

binaryOps["×"] = { $0 * $1 }
binaryOps["÷"] = { $1 / $0 }

newValue = binaryOps["÷"]?(6, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of my errors, @Nate Cook. I really appreciate it.